# Why is taking the mean RMSE sometimes so far off overall RMSE?

Tags: mean, approximation, rms, geometric-mean

I'm working with a multi-threaded program, which splits a dataset into N chunks, and evaluates some regression model's performance, predicting a score for each item in each chunk.

I'm using RMSD as the evaluation metric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation

My initial approach for calculating overall RMSD was as follows:

Have each thread calculate RMSD for its chunk, and then take the average of these.

However, I soon found that this approach sometimes results in an estimated RMSD that is far from the actual RMSD.

In the end, I decided to instead make each thread calculate the summed square error, and then I can calculate overall RMSD at the end, when all threads are joined, without relying on mean.  However, I'm left wondering how to explain what went wrong with the mean approach.

I'm confused as to why the mean RMSD is sometimes so far off the actual RMSD, even when the mean covers data chunks from the entire dataset.  I.e. we're not working with a small sample here.  It's more like we're working with evenly sized electoral constituencies.

For a basic example of how mean chunked RMSD can deviate from the actual RMSD, take this example:

$
\frac{                                                                                        
    \sqrt{                                                                              
        \frac{
            (e_1-o_1)^2+(e_2-o_2)^2    
        }    
        {2}    
    } + \sqrt{                                   
        \frac{                         
            (e_3-o_3)^2+(e_4-o_4)^2   
        }    
        {2}
    }    
}{2}    
\approx    
\sqrt{                                                                                                
    \frac{                                                    
        (e_1-o_1)^2+(e_2-o_2)^2+(e_3-o_3)^2+(e_4-o_4)^2    
    }{4}    
}
$

Above, RMSD is independently calculated across two splits of the dataset: $(\langle e_1, o_1\rangle,\langle e_2, o_2\rangle)$ and $(\langle e_3, o_3\rangle,\langle e_4, o_4\rangle)$.  $e_*$ represents the expected scores, and $o_*$ represents the observed/predicted scores.  The mean of the two calculations was then taken as an approximation of the whole.  I would have expected the above approximation to hold well, because we're basically just aggregating the RMSD scores from different splits of the dataset.

However, subbing in the values: $(e_1-o_1) = 20$, $(e_2-o_2) = 100$, $(e_3-o_3) = 0$, $(e_4-o_4) = 11$, we get $5.05 (RMSD_{1,2}) \approx 5.73 (RMSD_{3,4})$, which is way off.

My question isn't really about whether the above is way off (it clearly is, and I'm sure there are worse examples).  I'm instead looking to understand the intuition for why the approximation was way off.  Until this instance, I would have believed that any form of mean taken across the entire population size would be highly accurate if not entirely accurate.  A related question: would geometric mean be more appropriate here than arithmetic mean?

Comment: [Jensen's inequality?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality) The square root is a concave function, so $\sqrt{\operatorname{E}(X)} \geq \operatorname{E}\left(\sqrt{X}\right)$.